# Wireless Card Driver for Dell Mini 1012 using Ubuntu 12.04 not detected?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell-mini-10

I have tried every solution given on the forums and the original "Wireless Card Driver for Dell Mini 1012 using Ubuntu 12.04?" question here in Ask Ubuntu and I am still not able to get my wireless card working on my mini 1210 with 12.04, everything else is working fine but the wireless card. Is there another solution other than:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know it's similar question or not. but i have answer for this similar question in here : [WiFi driver problem with ubuntu 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259633/wifi-driver-problem-with-ubuntu-10-10/259639#259639)
Maybe it will help u.  Try ndiswrapper.With ndiswrapper you can using windows wifi driver at "base" driver. i have try one years ago and it's quit stable without any problem.

```
Download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/
Extract the contents of archive.

Open your terminal, cd to the directory where you have extracted it and then run the following commands:

make distclean clean
make
sudo make install

Download WiFi driver (Windows version) from ur vendor pc.

If it's in zip format, extract it. Be sure that you have the *.inf file in driver. Go to folder driver using terminal and run the following commands:

sudo ndiswrapper -i filename***.inf  

Check again by running:

ndiswrapper -m 

Restart Ubuntu and try again.
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this sounds strange but I had a similar problem.

The cure was changing the broadcast channel on wireless router to a lower number, like channel 1 or channel 2.

Then found my wireless on laptop connected perfectly and stays connected for as long as I wish.

This is easy to do and takes very little time. I hope it works for you.

Comment: While changing the broadcast channel can often help, in this situation, the problem is that the Ubuntu system does not have a driver working to use the wireless card in the first place. If you can't connect to your wireless card, then you can't use your wireless card to connect to a wifi network on any channel.