# WiFi driver problem with ubuntu 10.10

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 10.10 on my Dell Inspiron 1564 laptop. But I cannot connect to internet using my wireless home router. It's probably missing the device driver.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: 10.10 was not lts, any special reason to be on such old version. Also edit question and include result of `lspci` , `sudo lshw -c network` & `rfkill list all`

Comment: I had 10.10's optical image drive, else no other special reason. If  wifi drivers are available in-source in latter versions I can try downloading and installing latest ubuntu versions.

Comment: The driver may be there may be not. But you can install them easily. Chance of recognizing newer hardware will be high on a upgraded OS. The driver may require newer kernel support.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.10 is very old and you should upgrade :)

Have you tried installing `ndiswraper`?

- [Download it from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/)
- Extract the contents of archive.
- Open your terminal, `cd` to the directory where you have extracted it and then run the following commands:

  ```
  make distclean clean
  make
  sudo make install
  ```
- Download WiFi driver (Windows version) from Dell's website as your laptop is is manufactured by Dell.
- If it's in zip format, extract it. Be sure that you have the `*.inf` file in driver. Go to folder `driver` using terminal and run the following commands:

  ```
  sudo ndiswrapper -i filename***.inf
  ```
- Check again by running:

  ```
  ndiswrapper -m
  ```
- Restart Ubuntu and try again... or read the `man` page of `ndiswraper` first :)